# laravel - fulfilling legacy API calls including ? parameters

Tags: laravel

I have a need to handle API calls from a legacy system which include query string parameters.

e.g. /customer/?id=1

I can't seem to get the parameters.

Comment: did you try `request()->input('id')` ?

Comment: Try `INPUT::get('id')`

Comment: It die dumps with the parameter missing.

`Route::get("/customer/{any}", function ($any) {
`
`       dd($any);
`
`   })->where('any', '(.+)?');